# How to extract interval lengths (period)? (Using Fourier transform?)

Tags: fourier-transform

Imagine I have an event that repeats regularly, every two years.

I can represent it using a series of Dirac Delta functions like so:

$$
f(x) = \delta(x+4)+\delta(x+2)+\delta(x)+\delta(x-2)+\delta(x-4)+\delta(x-6)
$$
[f(x)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WCIa.png)

And I can use Fourier transform to tell me what is the interval:
$$\hat f(\omega) = FT(f(x))$$
$$\hat f(T) = |2\pi/\hat f(\omega)|$$
[|f(T)|](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjJkw.png)

Where the rightmost high peak sits above 2 and, if I change that interval, the peak also moves.

Now suppose the interval changes once:
$$
g(x) = \delta(x+4)+\delta(x+)+\delta(x)+\delta(x-3)+\delta(x-5)+\delta(x-7)
$$
[g(x)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHI4f.png)

Now, however, the $|\hat g(T)|$ has two equivalent peaks at 1.789 (~ 9/5?) and 2.252 (~ 9/4?), with the function equaling zero at both 2 and 3.

[|g(T)|](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07ZyG.png)

**How could I modify this process, to obtain something that would tell me there is a mix of period 2 and period 3 intervals? Either as two separate peaks or alternatively as a peak that ends up somewhere in between them** (although that might be what my current approach already does)**?**

**Also, how would I formalize the "the biggest peak on the right"?**

Another application could be to determine (a shifting) heart rate from timestamps of individual heartbeats.

Any insight welcome, thank you.